# What is the best way to reach css hover effect over label or css class switch when label pressed in nativescript (angular)

Tags: nativescript

It seems that css hover styling is unsupported in nativescript(angular). So how can I change the class of label when mouse is over? Something like this but its not working...

```
<Label text="Restricted" class="sideLabel" [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: hover==true  ? 'lightgrey' : 'grey' }" ></Label>
```

Also I'm interested in onTap event, how to switch class when label is pressed and how to switch to default class when label is released...

For now in template:

```
<Label class="sideLabel" (touch)="onTouch($event)" text="AAAAAAAAAAA" ></Label>
```

and in .ts file:

```
  onTouch(args: TouchGestureEventData) {
console.log(args.action);
let label:Label;
label = <Label>args.object
switch (args.action) {
  case 'up':
    label.cssClasses.delete("pressed");
    break;
  case 'down':
    console.log(args.object)
    label.cssClasses.add("pressed");
    break;
  default:
    break;
}}
```

CSS

```
.pressed {
color: blue;
}
```

In console i can see that pressed class is added and removed but this not make any change on the label. Any idea how to switch label class when label is pressed and released?

Comment: Curious what you're building with mouse support for hover with Android/iOS apps? Is it a terminal type application (POS)?

Comment: I just need hover effect when mouse/finger is over...

Comment: In that case, why don't you use a `Button` with CSS pseudo-selector `:active`. Read more on [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/button#styling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see any changes because you only change classes Set, but not notify NativeScript about it (`_onCssStateChange` method).

Bub in your case, I think it is better to use `addPseudoClass`/`deletePseudoClass` methods on a label (which notify NativeScript about pseudo class changed) - [Playground example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=lTxtUl).